# When to rebuild an image in docker?

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-image

I'm just starting with docker and I'm a bit confused with the volumes.
Suppose I have create a container with a volume, a folder from my computer and a folder from the container. Later in my pc folder I create a new sqlite database (so it is also created in the container, right?). When the container dies and you create a new container FROM THE SAME IMAGE, the database will still be there. Am I ok so far? But the image has been updated with this new database or what has happened? If not, is it better in these cases to rebuild the image and build a container? (or when should i rebuild the image? when i change environment variables?)
Thank you very much, I hope you can help me!

Comment: Volumes a mounted at container runtime, not image build time. In short: the image has no knowledge of volumes. Changes to the volumes are visible at runtime to the container when the volume is mounted. It is not necessary to rebuild the image if content of a volume changes, or a new volume is mounted.

Comment: But if I create a new container, are the changes made in the previous container still true? In this case, what actually happens is that it is taking the changes from the files on my PC? docker is costing me...

Comment: We cannot "change" images; they are immutable. We can change data in volumes. And if we start another container with the same volume as the first container, they will see the same data in that volume. If the volume permits read-write-access, the containers will see the changes made by each other. If we make changes to a running container (e.g. calling a package manager), those changes will be gone when the container is removed and recreated.

Comment: It's starting to become clearer to me. One last question (I promise haha)
When in docker compose for example I write this:
volumes:
       - ./project:/usr/src/app
(the first part is a path to my computer and the next part is a path to the container)
What I am doing is creating a volume that stores the changes both on my pc and in the container? (Is the name of the volume created automatically?) In this way, every time you build a container of that service with docker compose, will that volume be mounted?

Thank you very much for so much collaboration!

Comment: It is not duplicated. It is one and the same drectory, mounted into the container. If the container writes or modifies a file in the volume, it will be immediately visible on the docker host and vice-versa.

Comment: All understood! Infinite thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler case is if the database is in a separate container.  Consider this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: ['8000:80']
    environment: { PGHOST: db, ... }
  db:
    image: 'postgres:15.1'
    environment: { ... }
    volumes:
      - 'dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

First, notice that nothing at all is mounted on the `app` container.  If the code changes, you must rebuild the image, and if the image changes you must recreate the container.  (Compare to compiled languages like C++, Go, Rust, Java, or Elixir: if you change your code you generally must recompile the executable and then launch a new process.)

Hopefully the basic lifecycle of the `db` container and `dbdata` named volume are clear.

Now assume that a PostgreSQL 15.2 is released, and you change the `image:` accordingly.  The official image build can't know about your specific data, and it can't be included in the image.  Instead, the existing volume will get mounted into a new container running the new image.

[I'd recommend a setup like this if possible, with data stored in a database separate from your application container.  This is helpful if you ever want to run multiple replicas of your application, or if you're considering running the database on dedicated hardware or a hosted public-cloud offering.]

You should be able to generalize this to the setup you describe in the question.  If you have more like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: ['8000:80']
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data # containing the SQLite file
```

The bind-mounted `/app/data` directory actually has its storage outside the container.  If the container is deleted and recreated, the data is still there.  You do need to rebuild the image if the *code* changes, but the *data* is not stored in the image at all (and while it's accessible from the container, it's not stored in the container filesystem as such).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. A question arises: right in my current application I have the configuration that you mention:
volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data # containing the SQLite file
So what I have is not a volume, it is a bind-mounted?
According to what I had understood with this way of writing it, a volume was created where docker stores both the changes that arise in the container or in my pc, when a container died and a new one was run, that same volume was automatically mounted.

Comment: Continue...                                                                                                                       
But now I'm confused, what I'm actually doing is having a bind-mounted folder with my local folder, and every time I run a new container I access that folder?
I think that in both cases it is more or less the same, but I understood that the difference between bind-mounds and volumes was that the latter were stored by docker (please correct me if I'm wrong :) )

Comment: Correct, the major difference between named volumes and bind mounts is just whether Docker controls the storage or you use a specific host directory.  In both cases content in the mounted storage persists across containers.  Changes elsewhere in the container filesystem are lost when a container is deleted.